# Is it possible to use the scanner on a Canon ImageCLASS MF217w with Ubuntu (16.04)?

Tags: drivers, scanner, canon

I have the printer working, but scanning would be nice.
I don't see that the Canon website has a driver for scanning, just for printing.
It's not critical. I can use Windows, but I'm sure it's understood that it would be better to do this in Ubuntu.

Comment: What happens when you open **Simple Scan** app in Ubuntu 16.04? Try to scan using this app.

Comment: Simple Scan yields this message: "Failed to scan. Unable to connect to scanner."

When I choose "Change Scanner", it shows as the Scan Source:
"CANON Canon i-SENSYS MF210 Series." 

It doesn't let me scan, though, even after seeing that MF210 name there.